# Definition of an algebra over a monad by using equalities between natural transformations

Tags: category-theory, monads, natural-transformations, 2-categories, bicategories

In the definition of a monad, there are two ways to specify the equations:

1. equalities between natural transformations, or
2. equalities between morphisms

as is done [there on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)#Formal_definition).

In the usual definition of an algebra over a monad, equalities are between morphisms (1$^\text{st}$ way) like [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)#Algebras_for_a_monad). How do you reformulate these equations as equalities between natural transformations (2$^\text{nd}$ way)?

*What I tried:* I have been looking for the answer in the definition of a [left module over a monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+over+a+monad#definition) because it is a generalization of algebras in bicategories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A module for a monad $(T,\eta,\mu)$ on $D$ is a functor $F:C\to D$ together with a natural transformation $\alpha:T\circ F\to F$ such that $\alpha\circ\eta=\mathrm{id}_F$ and $\alpha\circ (\mu F)=\alpha\circ (T\alpha).$ Set $C$ to the terminal category to get an ordinary $T$-algebra.